# Wrong MIME type and HTML balise in JS & CSS files

Tags: javascript, html, css, mime-types

I'm actually working on Niagara4 and I need to create a web page to see live information from my server. I'm working with HTML5, CSS, JavaScript, Jquery, Require and BajaScript(JavaScript Framework working only on Niagara).

I've tried to put `type='application/javascript'` or `type='text/javascript'` to define JS and CSS(`type='text/css'`) file. Did nothing.
i've also heard about sniffing but i don't know much about it.

```
<head>
  <title>Tableau de gestion</title>

  <meta charset=utf-8" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ng-href="my/path/to/myStyle.css" />

  <script data-main="JS" src="my/path/to/require.js"></script>

  <script type="application/javascript" src="My/path/to/baja.js"></script>

  <script type="application/javascript" src ="My/path/to/jquery.js"></script>

  <script type="application/javascript" src="My/path/"></script>

</head>
```

When I want to load it on Chrome or Firefox, HTML tags are put into my CSS and js files turning it impossible to read for my browser, creating a "SyntaxError: Expected expression, got '<'."

Also, I've got a "The script from “http://watsonniagara/prelogin” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type." for Firefox and "Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://watsonniagara/prelogin with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details." from Chrome.

(Do I really need to precise that I expect my CSS and JS files to NOT have HTML tags ?)

Comment: "Do I really need to precise that I expect my CSS and JS files to NOT have HTML tags?" — You might expect it, but the browser claims otherwise. You should probably **look** at the URLs you are loading to figure out what content is there and why it isn't your JS.

Comment: It is my JS, the point is that some random things put <!doctype HTML> <head> etc... in the start of all my imported files (JS and CSS)

Comment: Then you need to figure out where that is coming from.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. And I don't know... That's why I asked here. The path is good, the file is good too, but when it loads into my web page, it's taken as html file in the network section.